# How to talk and what phrases to use in English (in person) to a supervisor on her last day at work, who is steping down, and wish her good luck?

Tags: american-english

I am a intermediate ESL learner, working at retail in US, I don't know what sentences should should I use to thank my supervisor on her last day, something between formal and informal.

Answer (score 2):

There are no magic words.

You might start with "Good luck", and then it is more or less up to you. Do you know what she is going to do next?   Then wish her luck for that: "Good luck working in the head office" (for example) Or "Good luck with your retirement".  If you don't know what she is going to do next, then you can ask if she has any plans.

You can say, "I have enjoyed working with you", or "I hope we will get the chance to work together again sometime" (of course, only if that is true!)

If she has given you any special help you can thank her for her support but
don't thank her for her work (you work for her, she doesn't work for you). Don't feel you have to say anything, if it doesn't seem natural. Don't fret over it, it is nearly impossible to make a serious mistake in such a situation.  Even if you say "good luck with your retirement" and she is actually being promoted, it would just get quietly ignored.